# Generate Word document and attach/send email without saving?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, attachment

I have a string that contains html. I have been able to save it as a .doc file to my computer/server but I would like to be able to email it from the C# without saving it to the server first. what I have is:

```
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = "from@email.com";
        msg.To = "to@email.com";
        msg.Subject = "Subject";
        msg.Body = "Body";

        string body = "<html><head></head><body><p>Word doc body here</p></body></html>";
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        Attachment att = new Attachment(ms, "Interview-Questions-Template.doc", "application/application/msword");
        msg.Attachments.Add(att);

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPrimaryServer"]);
```

If I pull out the attachment they email will send. the error that I am getting is:

```
System.FormatException: The specified content type is invalid.
at System.Net.Mime.ContentType.ParseValue()
at System.Net.Mime.ContentType..ctor(String contentType)
at System.Net.Mime.MimePart.SetContent(Stream stream, String name, String mimeType)
at System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(Stream contentStream, String name, String mediaType)
at EmailClass.sendEmail(String To, String Bcc, String Cc, String From, String Subject, String body) in <i took out the file path>
```

The last line of the error is pointing to the line in the code that has:

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(ms, "Interview-Questions-Template.doc", "application/application/msword");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out, the problem was where I was converting the string into byte[]. by using a static method:

```
static byte[] GetData()
{
    string s = "<html><head></head><body><p>Word doc body here</p></body></html>";
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    return data;
}
```

the problem was solved.